# How do I create a button component that takes parameters on its onClick method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, parameters, components

Okay, I've been working at this for 2 days now and I need some help. I previously made a loot logging program for a game I play, and now I want to make it into a Webapp. I'm using React JS to build the app.

I need to make a button component that includes an onClick function and can take parameters. My app renders buttons equal to the length of the loot table for the selected monster (so only the number of buttons needed are made) using a for loop. These buttons need to have an onClick method that takes a value parameter (the value is the index of an array if it matters. The array stores the loot table).

I thought I could just generate the button name by referencing {this.props.name} and the value it needs to pass by using {this.props.value}.

```
var Button = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 
        {this.props.id})}>{this.props.name}</button>
    },

    onClick: function(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
});

React.render((<Button name="test" id={1} />), 
document.getElementById('example'));
```

For testing purposes, the button is just drawn in a div with class 'example'.

I've tried to find the examples of something like this working, but I can't find anyone who wants to dynamically create buttons that also pass parameters like I need to do for my webapp. Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following code you wrote:

```
return <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 
        {this.props.id})}>{this.props.name}</button>
```

There is an error in the onClick binding. it should look like this:

```
return <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 
        this.props.id)}>{this.props.name}</button>
```

There are redundant brackets around this.props.id

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem! I didn't know the brackets around the onClick method were enough to not have to do it again when inserting a property.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a closure for each button's `onClick` while generating them:

```
const Button = ({ name, onClick }) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick}>{ name }</button>
    )
}

const List = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            { [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map((value, index) => {
                const onClick = () => { /* use index here */ }
                return <Button onClick={onClick} name={value}/>
            }) }
        </div>
    )
}
```

as an example. keep in mind I'm using ES6/JSX instead of `React.createClass` (for my sanity and because it's what I'm familiar with).

Besides, it doesn't make sense for the button to be responsible for handling the `onClick` logic - it should only be responsible for passing the event back to the relevant "subscribers"